# brew install fails downloading from ghcr.io - macOS Mojave

Tags: homebrew

On one of the 2 macOS Mojave systems I have, several `brew install` commands fail downloading files from the `https://ghcr.io` site, but it works fine on the other computer (same OS version: 10.14.6).

For example, here's an attempt on the computer where it fails:

```
> brew install rebar3
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 1 formula.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1k

curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
Error: Failed to download resource "openssl@1.1_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/manifests/1.1.1k
>
```

Some other `brew install` commands not reaching to the `https://ghcr.io` are completing fine, but all the ones that try to download from that site fail.

Is this a license certificate problem?  If so where can I learn more about how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem with the help of the Homebrew crew. See the full discussion [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1419).

**Overview**

The problem was that my system curl (version 7.54.0) was not working properly.  To solve the problem I had to install a new version of curl and force Homebrew to use it.  I still do not know *why* my system curl was failing though but at least I can use Homebrew again.

**Details**

Here's what I did in details:

- Built curl from source using Microsoft vcpkg (see instructions [here](https://curl.se/docs/install.html)
- Installed that new curl in my PATH (in my case I have a ~/bin directory before where the system directories in my PATH for that purpose, where I place various symlinks, I created a curl symlink in there).
- Temporarily set:

  `export HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1`

  `export HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH=/path/to/my/new/curl`

  - Used that environment to run `brew install curl` to get curl from Homebrew.
- Then added

  `export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL=1`

  in my environment setup to force Hombrew to use that new curl.

Now Homebrew is working properly again.

Comment: It didn’t work for me

Comment: @Fayçal Did you solve the problem differently or still have the problem?

Comment: I still have it

Comment: Try to install a new version of curl, try curl by itself, make sure it works and if it does not make sure it's not a network-related issue. If you're able to download files with curl, and can't get Homebrew to use that curl with the instructions above, you may want to ask the Homebrew team.   They'll need to know more about what your environment is and what you tried.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @mkl Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

I installed `curl` from homebrew (`brew install curl`) and, without changing paths or anything else to use the keg-only version, it seemed to fix the ghcr.io HTTP errors I was receiving for several packages.

Comment: For me, `brew install curl` fails for the same reason as the OP - can't access ghcr.io

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing a similar issue this morning where brew wouldn't update, nor could I install new packages. It looks like it was due to an outage at GitHub:

Apr 27, 2023 - 09:30 UTC
Update - Packages is now experiencing degraded availability. We are continuing to investigate.